# Not doing a if statement in a promise

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm making a quote generator, and if you spam it too much it pulls up a undefined.

I tried to make a if statement, where if the innerHTML is defined, it will just change it to

`"Sorry, we couldn't find a quote for you. Please try again later."`

Here is the code

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn")
let quote1 = document.getElementById("quote")




function quote(){

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': '',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'quotes15.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
    };

    fetch('https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response =>
            quote1.innerHTML = response.content)
            if (quote1.innerHTML === "undefined") {
                quote1.innerHTML = "Sorry, we couldn't find a quote for you. Please try again later."
            }
}
```

and this is the error

```
script.js:17          GET https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/ 429
```

Comment: Might not be the best idea to post your API key here on the Internet so that everyone can see it.

Comment: and what does `quote1.innerHTML` end up being

Comment: You're getting an HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response, which indicates that you're exceeding the quota of RapidAPI per second or so.

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying jaromanda

Comment: @AymaneHrouch

How would i give out a different message to the html if that happens?

Comment: the code should do what you want, albeit in an odd fashion ... I'd do `quote1.innerHTML = response.content ?? "Sorry, we couldn't find a quote for you. Please try again later.";`

Comment: @sscottdev you need to catch the error then do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the error, if you catch it display the error message you want.

```js
fetch('https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response =>
            quote1.innerHTML = response.content)
         .catch(err => {
               quote1.innerHTML = "Sorry, we couldn't find a quote for you. Please try again later."
          })
```